# serialize/deserialize decoder context?

Tags: ffmpeg, libav

Is it possible to store and load decoder contexts to resume a decoding session across process launches?

Context/Goal: use video compression to send image data over an expensive link; use intermediate frames almost exclusively (hours in between key frames). Allow consumer side to resume decoding in the event of interruption without requiring new key-frames from producer side.

Answer (score 1):

There was an [avcodec_copy_context](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.0/group__lavc__core.html#gae381631ba4fb14f4124575d9ceacb87e) but it has been deprecated, also because it was not actually copying a context but only its parameters.

In the [modern api](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/5.1/group__lavc__core.html) (some miscellanea functions also [here](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__misc.html)) there doesn't appear to be anything that would allow to save/load a `AVCodecContext`.

I was looking for a similar solution for being able while decoding to jump back and forth in the video to precise frames by storing codec context in between keyframes so to reduce the gap between keyframes. This unfortunately doesn't appear to be a possibility.

Maybe the solution could be similar to you do when you want to trim a video choosing a start frame in between keyframes (see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44291321/ffmpeg-trim-by-remux-doesnt-write-a-keyframe)):

- Create an encoder specular to the decoder (you probably want to pass the same encoding parameters used by the initial producer)
- At the time you need to stop your decoding, save the seek position in the file
- Send the last decoded frame to the encoder, flush it and grab the packet. That should be a keyframe.

When you resume, seek to the position you had arrived in the file, and send first of all to the decoder the packet you had grabbed before. This should hopefully put you in a *similar* state to that you were in when decoding stopped. Then resume reading packets from your stream and sending them to the decoder.

This is not tested, and reading what has been written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44291819/2436175), it might actually not work, especially for some codecs.